# How to create master branch in remote repositories?

Tags: git, commit, atlassian-sourcetree, init

I encounter an issue when I create a bare repository. Here is my step:

1. Create a folder named `Test` in a `C:\` as a remote repository
2. Create repository in sourcetree and select `C:\Test`
3. Input command `git init --bare` in terminal
4. Clone `C:\Test` to my local folder `D:\Test`

However, I can't see master branch in both `C:\Test` and `D:\Test`. How can I create a master branch? Thanks

PS: my `C:\Test` has hooks, info, objects, refs, config, description, HEAD. Do I need to check in them and make them as master branch?

Comment: Commit something to the repo. After a `git ini` the repo is empty.

Comment: @fredrik Thanks for your reply. But what should be the procedure? After git init --bare actually there are lots of files as I listed in "PS"

Comment: You do that on you clone, not on the bare repo - it doesn't have a workspace for you to commit on. Go to your clone and use `git add`, `git commit` and you probably want `git push` as well.

Comment: I would suggest walking through one of the many excellent git tutorials available online first, and then coming back here if you still have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I explained in "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096880/6309)", an initialized repository (bare or not) has 0 branch.

You need, in the non-bare repository `D:\Test`, to create, add and commit a file, in order for any branch (here the master branch by default) to be created.
You can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27636368/6309).

Then: `git push -u origin` master will update the remote bare repository.