# Cant create new branch while retaining master branch

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

After I try to create new branch by either commands new branch is either not created or master is gone.   If I use command  `git branch newBranch`  branch is not created.
If I use command `git checkout -b newBranch`  new branch is created but master branch is gone.
`

Comment: Master branch is gone ? Does it means if you run "git branch" command , there is no master branch ?

Comment: yes, it appears that new branch just replaces master branch. If I want to get master branch back, I run  checkout -b master and again only master branch is there.

Comment: Do you understand what a branch is? If you checkout a branch, you change your worktree (the files you can see) to match that branch. It’s like a teleportation machine: you can say “I want to be in London” or “I want to be in Paris” and poof, you are there. But you cannot be in London and Paris at the same time. If you jump to Paris, then London “is gone”.

Answer (score 1):

First, use the new [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) command, not the [old confusing `git checkout` one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

```
 git switch -c newBranch
```

Second, make sure you have a `master` branch to begin with, meaning `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches` shows at least one commit in the `master` branch.
Not "`origin/master`", but `master`.
You can list *all* branches with `git branch -avv`.

If you had zero commit in a newly initialized repository, then there would be no branch at all, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62208526/6309).

The [OP mat1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7601359/mat1) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62230863/cant-create-new-branch-while-retaining-master-branch/62231453?noredirect=1#comment110075341_62231453):

> I have made first push to remote repo, now it works.
>   Because I didn't have made initial commit and push , that is why I could not create branch.

Comment: git switch -c newBranch   doesnt create new branch, neither it switches to new branch since new branch doesnt even exists.

Comment: @mat1 What version of Git are you using? [`git switch -c` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt--cltnew-branchgt) is meant to *create* a new branch.

Comment: git version 2.16.1.windows.1

Comment: @mat1 Can you update first to Git 2.27? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: Before updating git I have made first push to remote repo, now it works. Because I didnt have made initial commit and push , thats why I could not create branch.